# Android Telegram app crash on specific devices

Tags: android, telegram

I have integrated Telegram in one of my apps.
Its working fine on many devices and Android version, but crashing on Android 4.4, Samsung Galaxy S3.

The error log that I am getting is:

```
org/telegram/SQLite/SQLitePreparedStatement
        java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
        java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:421)
        java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:362)
        java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        org.telegram.android.NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(NativeLoader.java:196)
        org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:188)
        android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4368)
        android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
        android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.telegram.SQLite.SQLitePreparedStatement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.bcd.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.bcd.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
        dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
        java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:421)
        java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:362)
        java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        org.telegram.android.NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(NativeLoader.java:196)
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Before all, as the above error seems, there's naming problem in the native source code and maybe it emanates from changing in package name of the project. 
You should change package name in all native source code and then rebuild it.
Replace in path the two followings cases in **jni** folder:

```
Java_org_telegram_
org/telegram/
```

with the style of naming your packages, like the examples below:

```
Java_org_telegram_example_
org/telegram/example/
```

In the above example, the package name is:

```
org.telegram.example.messenger
```

Comment: I did not get you, the package name of source folder is "org.telegram". What to do in jni ?

Comment: According to Telegram docs to publish Telegram app you must change package name. and if you did, so you should do the above steps (A.S.: right click on jni folder in Telegram source > Replace in path)  in order to Telegram works correctly.